# Matching email domains with Email addresses

Tags: sql, email, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables Table A and Table B in MS Access 2010.
Table A contains customer data and has a column called [email address] with full email addresses like abc@gmail.com.
Table B has a column called Email_domain that contains domain names (after '@' sign in email. For Example gmail.com or yahoo.com)
I need a sql query to extract data from Table A that matches email domains in Table B?

```
Table A
-------

Cust_Name   |   Email
___________________________________
Martin      |   martin@gmail.com

Hussey      |   hussey@yahoo.com

William     |   will@inbox.co

Table B
-------

Email_Domain
____________
gmail.com

inbox.co
```

Comment: Can you show your work so far?

Answer (score 2):

The best way will be to use a sub-query.

```
SELECT Cust_Name, Email
FROM TableA
WHERE Iif(InStr(Email, '@') > 0, Mid(Email, InStr(Email, '@') + 1), '') IN
   (SELECT Email_Domain FROM TableB)
```